# All intents leading to mainactivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is a code for one of my Android studio java classes:

```
 Button button1; //log in
 Button button2; //sign up

    public View.OnClickListener button1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){

            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginActivity);


        }};

    public View.OnClickListener button2Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){
            Intent signupActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(signupActivity);


        }};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setOnClickListener(button1Listener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(button2Listener);
}
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    Button button, button2;
    public FirebaseAuth auth;
    public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authlistener;
    String email, pass;
    ProgressBar bar;

    public View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){
            email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            pass = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
            createUser();

        }};

    public View.OnClickListener backButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){
            Intent backtoMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FrontPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(backtoMain);

        }};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button2.setOnClickListener(backButtonListener);
    }

    public void createUser(){
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed, Password must be >=6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                    }
                });


    }
}
```

**Login Activity:**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    Button button;
    public FirebaseAuth Auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authlistener;
    String email, pass;
    ProgressBar bar;

    public View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view){
            email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            pass = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
            logInUser();

        }};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        bar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        authlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in

                } else {
                    // User is signed out

                }
                // ...
            }
        };
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Auth.addAuthStateListener(authlistener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (authlistener != null) {
            Auth.removeAuthStateListener(authlistener);
        }
    }

    public void logInUser(){
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent loggedInActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loggedin.class);
                            startActivity(loggedInActivity);

                        }
                        else{

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an error, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });


    }
}
```

So, I have 2 buttons, "login," and "sign-up" and both should lead to a different intent. The `sign-up` leads to the `mainactivity.class` which is the sign up page basically.

However, even though I have mapped `button1` to the loginAcitivty class, it still goes to `MainActivity.class`. Why is this happening?

Comment: show the rest of the code

Comment: Maybe both buttons have the same listener set?

Comment: Be sure that the buttons don't have same listener

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi, they do not, I've updated the code.

Comment: @PavneetSingh, I have added the listener and the whole other classes too

Comment: Is it button1 or button 3 ? You find the ressource name `button3` and `button4`. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `LoginActivity` in this you have set `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` it is inflating the content layout of `activity_main`

> The layout you are inflating in both the activities are same..

Comment: One more reason to name correctly the item in the layouts. This would have trigger and exception during a findView

Comment: Its because it is unable to find the Id check the Id does it exist in the layout or not ....

Comment: The opposite ... every ids are present in both layout because they are name `button`, `editText`, `editText2`, ... so everything works perfectly, well except that it's working on the wrong screen. That's why he thought his Intent was heading the wrong way. There were NO exception.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this,

```
Button button1; //log in
    Button button2; //sign up

   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginActivity);


        }};

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signupActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(signupActivity);


        }};
```

Comment: I can do this, but why does my way have an issue?

Comment: problem with your listeners and in your code you are not finding the view to listen.

Comment: @KiranDsouza not finding the view ? The button ? Well `.setOnClickListener` would throw an exception then...

Comment: you need the View object of the layout and call findViewById() on it